# Problem with simple Inheritance for class representing arithmetic expressions

Tags: python, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, abstract-methods

I have a problem implementing a simple class hierarchy with arithmetic expressions.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

and the same for the other operations, addition, subtraction, division, etc.

My code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Wyrazenie(ABC):
    # @abstractmethod
    def Oblicz(self):
        pass


class Operator(Wyrazenie):
    w1 = Wyrazenie()
    w2 = Wyrazenie()
    def __init__(self, wy1, wy2):
        self.w1 = wy1
        self.w2 = wy2
    #def Oblicz(self) -> int:
    #    pass


class Zmienna(Wyrazenie):
    zmienna=""
    slownik={}
    def __init__(self, klucz, wartosc):
        self.slownik.update({klucz: wartosc})

    def Oblicz(self):
        return self.slownik.get(self.zmienna)


class Stala(Wyrazenie):
    wartosc=0
    def __init__(self, wartosc1):
        self.wartosc=wartosc1

    def Oblicz(self):
        return self.wartosc


class Dodaj(Operator):
    def __init__(self, wy1=None, wy2=None):
        super().__init__(wy1, wy2)

    def Oblicz(self) -> int:
        return self.w1.Oblicz() + self.w2.Oblicz()


class Odejmij(Operator):
    def __init__(self, wy1=None, wy2=None):
        super().__init__(wy1,wy2)

    def Oblicz(self) -> int:
        return self.w1.Oblicz() - self.w2.Oblicz()


class Pomnoz(Operator):
    def __init__(self, wy1=None, wy2=None):
        super().__init__(wy1,wy2)

    def Oblicz(self) -> int:
        return self.w1.Oblicz() * self.w2.Oblicz()


class Podziel(Operator):
    def __init__(self, wy1=None, wy2=None):
        super().__init__(wy1,wy2)

    def Oblicz(self) -> int:
        return self.w1.Oblicz() / self.w2.Oblicz()


z1=Zmienna("x", 4)
z2=Zmienna("y", 10)

#   4 * 10 + 10 - 5 = 45
wyr = Dodaj(Pomnoz(z1, Stala(10)), Odejmij(z2, Stala(5)))

wyr.Oblicz()

print("Wartosc wyrazenia=   \n")
print(wyr.Oblicz())
```

I don't know whether it's an issue with initializing `wy1`, `wy2` with `None` or whole wrong idea of representing such expressions. I tried to rewrite it from my Java class.

Answer (score 0):

I've traced your code down, and I found that the reason this error is occurring is ultimately because `Zmienna.Oblicz` is returning `None`.

The call `wyr.Oblicz()` is like this:

```
wyr (Dodaj) .Oblicz ->
  wyr.w1 (Pomnoz) .Oblicz ->
    wyr.w1.w1 (z1) (Zmienna) .Oblicz ->
      self (Zmienna) .slownik.get(self.zmienna) ->
        this call returned None
```

At the time `slownik.get` was called, `slownik` was a `dict` containing `{'x': 4, 'y': 10}`, and `self.zmienna` was an `str` containing `""`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're adding so much complication before fixing something basic, but here's what's happening:

- you call `wyr.Oblicz()`, which is `Dodaj.Oblicz()` (by the way, bad idea to name a method with capitals, it's very confusing as it looks like a class)
- it calls `self.w1.Oblicz()` before trying sum the result with something else, and it is the `Oblicz()` of the first parameter passed to `Dodaj(Pomnoz(z1, Stala(10)), Odejmij(z2, Stala(5)))`, so `Pomnoz.Oblicz()`
- it calls `self.w1.Oblicz()` before trying to multiply the result with something else, and it is the first parameter of `Pomnoz`, i.e. `zi`, which is `Zmienna("x", 4)`, so `Zmienna.Oblicz()`
- it calls `self.slownik.get(self.zmienna)`, but since `self.zmienna` is `""` and there is no entry for `""` in `self.slownik`, it returns `None`

That `None` is passed back and the multiplication then fails when `Pomnoz.Oblicz()` tries to perform it, as it cannot multiply `None` and an integer.

If you were using an IDE with a debugger, you could trace that yourself, by stepping into code as it's calling further functions - consider using something like PyCharm, Spyder, VSCode or any other or editor or IDE that has a debugging facility.